# Why are drawrectangle and drawtext using different resolutions from each other when printing

Tags: c#, printing, graphics, drawtext, drawrectangle

Briefly my problem is this. Given the same size constraints, TextRenderer.DrawText and DrawRectangle produce the same sized correct output when sent to the Graphics object of a Panel, but  when sent to the Graphics object of PrintPageEventArgs e (ie when physically printing) they produce output sizes that vary from each other and are located differently.

My program produces physical labels to stick on plant pots, pulling content and label style information from a database. This produces various label styles using text, pictures and boxes. Based on whether the field to draw is text or a box or a picture, different methods generate the output. Text is created using TextRenderer.DrawText, boxes by DrawRectangle, pictures by DrawImage. For a screen preview a panel is used to draw on, for the printer a PrintDocument.

Screen previews of labels, drawing on a panel, produce perfect results with correctly lined up and located fields. However when I transfer this to a printer, the text elements are being rendered at 1/6th the size and location of the graphical objects. (I think the value relates to it being a 600dpi printer. A 200dpi printer is rendering the text at half size.)

What I think it might boil down to is this. Are DrawText and DrawRectangle using a common resolution on the screen but different resolutions from each other on the printer, and if so why. I can see that I could adjust one set of values only when printing, but I would like to understand the underlying reason and address that instead.

I have written the code below which reproduces the effect. It requires a form with a panel on (350 x 450) and two buttons to trigger the events. On the screen it produces a rectangle with the word 'Bergenia' within and almost filling it. However, on the printer the word 'Bergenia' is much smaller and located well to the top left.

Thank you.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

namespace TrialPrintingApp
{
    public partial class FormLabel : Form
    {
        public FormLabel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FormLabel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void buttonScreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateLabel(panel1.CreateGraphics());           
        }

        private void buttonPrinter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.PrintPage += (sender1, args) => PrintRoutine(sender, args);
            pd.Print();
        }

        private void PrintRoutine(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            CreateLabel( e.Graphics);
        }

        public void CreateLabel(Graphics formGraphics)
        {
            //Draw Text
            Font useThisFont = new Font("Arial", 45, FontStyle.Bold);
            Point P = new Point(20, 100);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(formGraphics, "Bergenia", useThisFont, P, Color.Black);

            //Draw Box
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Coral, 5);
            formGraphics.DrawRectangle(p, 20, 100, 300, 100);
            p.Dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: TextRenderer.DrawText is for the screen, Graphics.DrawString is for printing.  Avoid CreateGraphics.

Comment: Thank you. Brilliantly simple. I've applied this to my main program and the problem is solved. Could you possibly clarify your last comment 'avoid CreateGraphics'

Comment: Graphics drawn with a Graphics  from control.CreateGraphics will not __persist__. - You can test the persistance of your graphics by doing a Minimize/Maximize sequence.. - The correct way is to keep a list of things to draw and whenever that list changes `Invalidate` the control you draw on. All drawing should be in the `Paint` event, using `e.Graphics` there! - The code used for printing does it right, though.

Comment: Thank you, that's useful. I think my main program does it right, the code above was cut to the bare minimum for clarity.

Comment: I believe `Paint` is not always the best option to draw stuff. To be exact, it is the best (and perhaps only correct) option for screen inter-action, such as painting drag&drop graphics, design modes (displaying progress graphics when drawing line or other entities using a cursor), etc. For drawing without interaction, it's better to create graphics over a bitmap, draw, and show the bitmap. But the differences become apparent only when you have hundreds to thousands of entities to deal with, no worries needed when doing simple drawing.